Prove $\int_0^\infty (1-\exp(-\operatorname{Ei}(t)))dt=\int_0^\infty\exp(-t-\operatorname{Ei}(t))dt$
How to prove $$\int_0^\infty (1-\exp(-\operatorname{Ei}(t)))dt=\int_0^\infty\exp(-t-\operatorname{Ei}(t))dt$$ where $\operatorname{Ei}(t)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\exp(-xt)}{x} dx$? This constant value is known as Golomb-Dickman constant. According to
Shift Register Sequences (Solomon Wolf Golomb) at page 192, these two expressions are equivalent. However, he leaves it as an exercise. I want to know how to prove it.

Since $\mathrm{Ei}(t)=\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{x}dx$,  noting that $t\cdot(1-e^{-\mathrm{Ei}(t)})\to0$ as $t\to\infty$, and
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{Ei}(t)=-\frac{e^{-t}}t
$$
we can integrate the first integral by parts:
$$
\int_0^\infty \left(1-e^{-\mathrm{Ei}(t)}\right) dt=
-\int_0^\infty t \frac{d}{dt}\left[1-e^{-\mathrm{Ei}(t)}\right] dt=
\int_0^\infty t\cdot\left(-\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\right)\cdot e^{-\mathrm{Ei}(t)} dt=\int_0^\infty  e^{-t-\mathrm{Ei}(t)} dt
$$
Q.E.D.

$$(t-t\exp(-\operatorname{Ei}(t)))'=1-\exp(-\operatorname{Ei}(t))-\exp(-t)\exp(-\operatorname{Ei}(t))=(1\text{st})-(2\text{nd})$$
$t-t\exp(-\operatorname{Ei}(t)))$ is $0$ when $t=0,\infty$.
Thus, integrate this, we prove it.
